# ReactJs - Routers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, router

estoy tratando de hacer con react un login.- 
[image: inicio sesion]

principal app.js llamo a otro componente login para que me aparezca primero en la pantalla

;

```
  <div className="App">
    <Login />      
</div>
```

al hacer click en ingresar quiero que automaticamente me lleve al la web page Principal

desde el login hice esto en el link Iniciar

```js
  <div className="link-container">
        <Link to="/Principal">Ingresar</Link>
      </div>
```

y el route

```
    <Switch>           
          <Route path="/principal" component={Principal} />            
        </Switch>                 
        </BrowserRouter>
```

el BrowerRouter tiene como inicio al comienzo del return del login, bueno, al hacer click en el Iniciar pasa esto.- 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

si pueden ver hace el route a Principal, si cambia la url actual. http://localhost:3000 la cambia a http://localhost:3000/Principal
pero el login no desaparece, que estare haciendo mal? desde ya muchas gracias

Comment: Asocia el login al index: `<Route exact="/" component={Login}/>`. Fíjate en el `exact`. La vista no cambia porque está haciendo match al index primero.

Comment: hola, gracias, al agregar ese route deja de funciona..

Answer (score 0):

Date cuenta de que estás cambiando a /Principal, mientras que la ruta la tienes definida en el path /principal. Trata de arreglar este typo y usar exact en las rutas.